# Computing the conditional expectation of $E[t^Y|X=k]$?

Tags: probability, summation, conditional-expectation

For $X\in $Bin($n,p$) and $Y|X=k \in$Bin($k,p$), I have the conditional expectation,
$$
E[t^Y|X=k]=\dots
$$
I know that I probably should use the formula;
$$
E[Y|X]=\sum_{y}y \cdot f(y|x),
$$
But how do I compute the conditional expectation? I never get the correct answer $(1-p+pt)^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, 
$$E[g(X)] = \sum_x g(x)P(X = x)$$
in the discrete case.

I will change the notation a little. In your case, if $X\sim \text{Bin}(m,p)$, and $Y|X\sim\text{Bin}(X,p)$, then
\begin{align*}
E[t^Y|X = n] = \sum_{k=0}^n t^k P(Y = k|X = n) = \sum_{k = 0}^n t^k\cdot\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
\end{align*}
In other words, **don't** use
$$E[Y|X]=\sum_{y}y \cdot f(y|x).$$
Try to take it from here.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But why is it $t^k$ and not $t^y$? Or can I view it as $t^y=t^k$?

Comment: @litmus It is, except $y$ is not a constant, it varies. So I used $k$, since $k$ is a typical index when using summation notation. Using little $y$ is fine too.

Comment: @litmus Also, I chose $n,k$ to make the binomial distribution recognizable.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help! So by using binomic terms and rewriting $t^k\cdot p^k = (tp)^k$ I get $ \dots = (1-p+tp)^n.$ But why did I get it raised to $n$? Or is this also a case where the final term can be seen as $n=k$ for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}$?

Comment: @litmus Recall that I made a few changes in the notation, so my notation will not match the answer given. Observe that I changed $k$ to $n$, so the final answer should be with an $n$:  $(1-p+pt)^k \to (1-p+pt)^n$.

Comment: @litmus Sorry for changing the notation. If you use the original letters and follow the **new** procedure, then everything will match.

Comment: No worries! I decided to view it as a $k$ to $n$ substitution and then substitute $k$ back in the end.